# Output PowerShell query to an email

Tags: powershell

Someone kindly produced the following PowerShell script for me to check if a number of computers were online or offline and output to a grid.  Now I would like to automate this as a scheduled task on a computer that outputs to a specific user by email.

How to develop the below script so that it would output to email?

```
$dt = new-object System.Data.DataTable
$cols=@("Location", "Hostname", "Status")
foreach ($col in $cols) {
    $dt.Columns.Add($col) | Out-Null
    }

$dt.rows.add("1", "3050-27222", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("2", "3050-27614", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("3", "3050-27623", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("4", "3050-27636", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("5", "3050-27625", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("6", "3050-27615", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("7", "3050-27616", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("8", "3050-27631", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("9", "3050-27637", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("10", "3050-27601", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("11", "3050-27606", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("12", "3050-27635", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("13", "3050-27638", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("14", "3050-27628", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("15", "3050-27622", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("16", "3050-27604", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("17", "3050-27613", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("18", "3050-27624", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("19", "3040-25508", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("20", "3050-27621", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("21", "3050-27634", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("22", "3050-27619", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("23", "3050-27640", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("24", "3050-27630", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("25", "3050-27632", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("26", "TBC", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("27", "3050-28448", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("28", "3050-27599", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("29", "3050-27617", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("30", "3050-27605", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("31", "3050-27603", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("32", "3050-27602", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("33", "3050-27620", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("34", "3050-27610", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("35", "3050-27626", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("36", "3050-27608", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("37", "3050-27618", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("38", "3050-27641", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("39", "3050-27609", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("40", "3050-27611", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("41", "3050-27607", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("42", "3050-28452", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("43", "3050-28457", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("44", "3050-27600", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("45", "3050-28709", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("46", "3050-27629", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("47", "3050-27639", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("48", "3050-28447", "Offline")
$dt.rows.add("49", "3050-27627", "Offline")

foreach ($row in $dt)
{
    if (Test-Connection $row.Hostname)
    {
        $row.Status = "Online"
    }
    else
    {
        $row.Status = "Offline"
    }
}

$dt | sort-object "Status"| Out-GridView
```

Comment: [`Send-MailMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage)...

Output to a File or CSV and send as attachment to an email:

```
$dt | sort-object "Status" | Out-File -FilePath C:\folder\attachment.txt #file
$dt | sort-object "Status" | Export-CSV C:\folder\file.csv -NoTypeInformation #csv

Send-MailMessage -From 'user01@example.com' -To 'user02@example.com' -Subject 'Sending the Attachment' -Body 'Connection Status' -Attachments 'C:\folder\file.txt' -SmtpServer smtp.example.com
```

Output to HTML and include in body of email:

```
$html_table = $dt | sort-object "Status" | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

Send-MailMessage -From 'user01@example.com' -To 'user02@example.com' -Subject 'Sending the Attachment' -BodyAsHtml $html_table -SmtpServer smtp.example.com
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of the advice, I went with James as it was the solution that came up first on screen.  I was able to set this as a scheduled task and email to me on a schedule :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take the $dt variable at the bottom of your script and export it to a CSV locally on the computer somewhere.

```
$dt | Export-CSV C:\report.csv -NTI
```

You can then use the Send-MailMessage command to send that CSV in an email. This will require finding out your SMTP server, and being able to relay mail through it.

```
Send-MailMessage -Attachments C:\report.csv -From from@domain.com -To to@domain.com -SmtpServer your.smtp.server.address
```